# .net6 mvc Get Host Address in program.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

My .net6 MVC application is hosted in IIS.
I want to get Website Name / Url in startup Program.cs file.

In MVC5 we have HostingEnvironment.ApplicationHost.GetSiteName()

I need similar code in .NET6 MVC.

Comment: Use following .  The array AddressList[] usually has the IPV6 as array item zero and IPV4 as array item one : string LocalHostName = Dns.GetHostName();
IPHostEntry LocalHostIPEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(LocalHostName);
IPAddress LocalHostIP = LocalHostIPEntry.AddressList[0];

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.
We have multiple website hosted in IIS.. eg. abc.domain.com, xyz.domain.com etc. i want to get the host name eg abc.domain.com.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your `program.cs` file like below.

1. **Program.cs**:

   In your `Program.cs` file, set up the host configuration:

   ```cs
   using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
   using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

   public class Program
   {
       public static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
       }

       public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
           Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
               .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
               {
                   webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
               });
   }
   ```
2. **Startup.cs**:

   In your `Startup.cs` file, inject the `IWebHostEnvironment` to access the website name or URL:

   ```cs
   using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
   using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
   using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

   public class Startup
   {
       private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
       private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _webHostEnvironment;

       public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment)
       {
           _configuration = configuration;
           _webHostEnvironment = webHostEnvironment;
       }

       public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
       {
           // Your configuration and services setup
       }

       public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
       {
           // Your middleware and routing configuration

           // Access the website name or URL from _webHostEnvironment
           string websiteName = _webHostEnvironment.ApplicationName;
           string websiteUrl = _webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath;

           // Use websiteName and websiteUrl as needed
       }
   }
   ```

`_webHostEnvironment.ApplicationName` provides the website name, and `_webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath` offers the root path of the website, which can be considered as the base URL when hosted in IIS.

Note that `_webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath` provides the physical file system path to the web root directory. If you need the actual URL, you may need to construct it based on your server configuration.